# Classical Full Fourier Series of f(x) converges uniformly to f(x)

Tags: fourier-series

Prove the classical full Fourier series of $f(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ if $f(x)$ is continuous of period $2\pi$ and its derivative $f'(x)$ is piecewise continuous.

How do I go about doing this question?

Comment: Do you know "Dini's Test"?

Comment: The idea is to write down the error at a given point in terms of an infinite series of integrals, then integrate by parts (moving the derivative to $f $). For high frequencies this introduces a factor which goes to zero as the frequency goes to infinity. Use that factor and Parseval's identity to get an error bound independent of $x$. (The bound should be something like $\| f' \|_{L^2}/N $).

Comment: For more info on this technique, look up "spectral convergence"; this is the basis of spectral methods for a class of problems whose solution is smooth.

Comment: @Ian Seems to me if we want that sort of argument it could be stated more simply: Integration by parts shows that $\widehat{f'}(n)=in\hat f(n)$. And $f'\in L^2$, so $\sum n^2|\hat f(n)|^2<\infty$. Hence $\sum|\hat f(n)|<\infty$, so the series converges uniformly.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich While that is simpler, expanding on it a bit hints at the fact that we can *keep integrating by parts* for sufficiently smooth $f$ to get better and better estimates.